# How set automatic (electric) indentation using clang-format in emacs?

Tags: emacs, auto-indent, clang-format

I want call `clang-format-region` when every *newline* or *tab* was pressed, not only `C-M tab`.

Comment: Does `electric-indent-mode` not do what you want?

Comment: @KnutForkalsrud: I think no, because indentation in Emacs just puts white spaces in the beginning of the lines, whereas `clang-format` formats the whole 'style' of code.

Comment: I see, clang-format-region delegates indentation to an external tool... Anyhow, clang-format-region needs a region. You won't necessarily have one when you press newline or tab. Also, where should the point (cursor) end up after the indentation command completes?

Comment: `clang-format-region` doesn't need a region. It just indent the current line when no region is selected.